# Hidden message in pictures 3

Tags: visual, rebus

Find the sentence behind these pictures.

```
"I am in very big trouble.
 They found some evidence that incriminates me.
```

The message continues with a more difficult hidden sentence:

[image]

**The order of the words / parts of words is exactly as on the image.**

*- For full size image, right-click the image → open in new tab.*

Answer (score 2):

Incomplete answer, but it's the best I can do for now. I'm going to specify what each picture looks like to me, and what I currently think they mean (mainly throwing random ideas, but the bold ones I think I have). Also note that anything in speech marks is saying it could just be the sound, not the word.

> Red Kidney Beans - (Bean? Kidney?) 
>  Green on Italian flag, said to represent the country's plains - (Plain? Green?) 
>  Signing a document - (Lease? Sign?) 
>  Eye of Horus - **"Eye" > I** 
>  Needle with thread - **"Needle" > Need all** 
>  Yolo - [Combine with next two pictures] 
>  Minus sign "Lo Spaccio" - [Yolo-Lo=Yo, combine with next picture] 
>  Iraq, with Ur noted specially - [Ur, combine with previous makes...] **Your** 
>  Tear gas grenade. - (CS/"See-Ess"? Tear? Gas? Riot?) 
>  Piranha Plant + L-shaped Pipe from Mario - (Pipe? Plant? L/"Ell"?) 
>  number one - (First? Uno?) 
>  Aye-aye - **I** 
>  NOT a CAN of Tuna. NotCan - **Cannot** 
>  Someone applying make-up - **Cover** 
>  Tea with a rewind symbol underneath - **"Tee" backwards > "Eet" > "It"** 
>  Music staff, with an A note - [A, combine with next clue] 
>  Someone holding a stopwatch and money - ["Loan" > Lone. Combine with previous for...] **Alone**

Which makes my (currently incomplete) answer:

> _ _ _, I need all your _ _ _, I cannot cover it alone.

Comment: "I cannot cover; I'm in deep trouble at the time." Aye-aye+"not-can+(makeup could be cover or cover-up)+mint-tea+treble+eighth+time.)

Comment: "Cover"'s a good idea. Not sure on the "treble-eighth" bit as that seems to be getting two clues from a single picture, but it might be right, I'll wait to see if jack responds. Also, I only just noticed the first comma, seperating the "Plain Lease" from the "Horus" meaning I was wrong and will edit them now too.

Comment: The note A is also called "La"
And "time is money", perhaps it's something like "is", "equivalent" or "tautology"?

Comment: also "They found some evidence" and the word "lease" being clearly the end of *some* word, suggests it could be PO-lice. Not sure how green ties into that though...

Comment: Finally the canister is not "smoke", apparently "CS" marking means it is filled with tear gas (it is also more consistent with the word "riot" then a smoke grenade)

Comment: Green is also the colour of hope, maybe hope+lease is hopeless.The stopwatch - limited time?

Comment: Perhaps time and money are "loan"? In that case the last part is "I can not cover it alone"

Comment: @Timoris Your  (currently incomplete) answer is correct.

Comment: Great to know. I also think @mr23ceec, that's probably the ending phrase, especially when I think he's saying "I need all your [something]" to someone before that.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can do.  Maybe someone else can build on this?

> Ben Greenley saw us needle Joe.
>  He recognized your picture first,
>  But you're not in as much (hot water?) trouble at this time.
>
>  "Bean+Green+Lease+Horus+needle+yolo-lo("Joe")
>
>  Iraq+cannister+pitcher+first,
>  Badger+"no-tuna"+smudge+(hot water? Mint-tea???)+treble+eighth+time."

Comment: I think it's a lemur, not a badger.

Comment: I think you are right. @Flater. I don't know what to do with it, though.

Comment: Looks like a possum.

Comment: The animal is an aye-aye.

Comment: The order of the words / parts of words is exactly as on the image.
Also, you answer is not even close.

Comment: Kidney-verde-sign="Kid never design?"

Comment: @Rob nope, check the other answer